# Make Eclipse RCP package from other bundle available in JavaScript

Tags: eclipse, rcp, nashorn

I have an Eclipse RCP application with the facility to evaluate a JavaScript text on the Nashorn JVM.

Bundle A implements the evaluation of the JS.

The JS script is referencing classes in Bundle B, eg. a enum class. But this Bundle B is not known by Bundle A. And Bundle B loads the classes dynamically by reading an external jar file.

Now when i use importPackage or Java.type i get an ClassNotFoundException.

In Bundle A, i can get retrieve an object from Bundle B from the JAR. With it's classloader  i can also access other classes from the JAR.

```
getBundleBObj().getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass( "my.ClassEnum" );
```

This succeeds.
Can I use this somehow, to make the package 'my.*' (from Bundle B) be available in the JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a java.lang.Class instance, you could expose it as a global variable to script and use "static" property on it.

In Java:

```
// Class yourClassObject = ...

// expose Class object as variable to your script
// "engine" is nashorn engine instance

engine.put("MyClass", yourClassObject);
```

In JavaScript:

```
var M = MyClass.static;
var obj = new M(); // create object
M.func(); // call static method
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the missing step.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest approach would be to have Bundle A providing an API or an extension point for Bundle B to consume in order to add its classloader or a few specific classes to the Nashorn engine which is instantiated in Bundle A.

Another approach is to look at Eclipse-BuddyPolicy that allows to get classloaders "leaking" between bundles": https://wiki.eclipse.org/Context_Class_Loader_Enhancements#Buddy_Class_Loading . But this happens to be a hack against OSGi that makes maintenance harder and code not portable to other OSGi containers than Equinox.